# Use YouTube API to get videos in Recommendation Section of a user

Tags: api, flutter, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I want to implement a feature in my Flutter App which requires knowing the Home Feed (the recommendation section you see on YouTube when you first open your app which is customised by YouTube's Algorithm for every user) how to do it using the YouTube API. I think the 'home' parameter is deprecated.

Comment: [DaImTo already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758495/how-to-get-home-feed-of-a-logged-in-user-using-youtube-api#comment119770537_67758495) to your question, @Pranjal Chaplot!

Comment: No he was asking for more clarification and hence I created a new Question

Comment: She answered by stating (quote): *a YouTube user may have a feed but thats not available in the API.* This is true: no API endpoint provides the home feed of a given user.

Comment: Oh ok, thank for the info.

Comment: @stvar is there any way I can get the recommendation feed of a new user who hasn't logged out which is basically defined by location (i guess) does YouTube API provide the list of home page videos in a region. If yes, how can I use it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, @Pranjal Chaplot, the answer is no: there's no endpoint that'll provide the info you're looking for.